# need to "build" a mysql command and exec it in a shell script

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell, command

I'm new to writing shell scripts.

I am attempting to create a database using a shell script. Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#create a new db
a="mysql -uuser -ppassword -e'create database $1;'"
exec $a
```

The command `exec mysql -uuser -ppassword -e'create database databaseName;'` works in a shell, but when I `sh` the script, I get the mysql help open...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to write and execute a shell script to create a mysql databse and a table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271925/how-to-write-and-execute-a-shell-script-to-create-a-mysql-databse-and-a-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the quotes, the simple quote prevent the variable expansion.
You can simply do like this in your script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #create a new db

    mysql -u user -p password -e "create database $1;"
```

Or you can try to place all your mysql commands in a file, let's say "dbname.sql".
And do this:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #create a new db

    mysql -u user -p password "$1" < "$1.sql"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you like use exec to run commands this can be a possible solution

```
    #!/bin/bash
    #create a new db
    programm="mysql"
    parameter[0]="-ppassword"
    parameter[1]="-uuser"
    parameter[2]="-ecreate database $1;"
    exec "$programm" "${parameter[@]}"
```

exec parameter are

`exec [-a NAME] [-cl] [COMMAND] [ARG...] [REDIRECTION...]`

command is `$programm` and the array `parameter` is the argument list.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use the 'cat' command and a pipe instead of using 'exec' .

```
cat /path/to/my/file | mysql -h localhost -u root -padmin
```